# Passing Object's Params into Rspec test with params.merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

In my rspec test, I create an object with factorygirl, and in my create controller, I need parameters in order to create an object. Since there are lots of parameters and connection with paperclip, I do not want to give them by hand.
My code is the following:

```
  it "should render correct JSON on success save" do
    @params = {}
    post(:create, @params.merge(:upload => FactoryGirl.create(:upload)))
    response.body.should == @upload.to_json
  end
```

So my problem is initializing the :upload's params. I'm already creating `@upload` object with factorygirl at the beginning with `before`

How should I solve this problem efficiently ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post` is not part of the spec, it is a change of state that occurs before the response so it should go in a `before` block.

The params don't need to be an instance variable (does anything in RSpec?), better to use a `let`.

```
context "When saving" do

 before do
   post(:create, params)
 end

 subject { response.body }

 context "That is successful" do
   let(:upload) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:upload) }
   let(:params){
     {:upload => upload }
   }
   it { should == upload.to_json }
 end

 context "That is not successful" do
   # do some failure stuff here
 end
end
```

Comment: It gives ' Failure/Error: post(:create, params)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stringify_keys' for "2":String' error. But I don't understand where 2 comes from :/ ?

Comment: 2 is the number of times, that I call FactoryGirl.create(:upload). But why does it cause an error ?

Comment: You didn't mention if you're using Capybara | rails-rspec | rack-test etc. I'm not sure why that error is thrown without more info. I've made a slight edit. Personally, I'd not create the `@upload` variable/model, because it's not needed. The `let(:upload) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:upload) }` does the creation and memoizes the object/hash, which means it will can be reused within further examples and it won't screw up an example by changing.